# CoverFlow Recycler View

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement a cover flow horizontal recycler view - Android,

I used this library:
https://github.com/ChenLittlePing/RecyclerCoverFlow

And everything works fine, but the problem is in RTL, when the app in RTL mode, the scroll direction is from left to right, it should be form right to left.

Comment: Have you considered using a normal Recyclerview with a `LinearLayoutManager` and an `orientation=horizontal` for this? The library you've linked hasn't been updated in over 2 years or more. You'd have to bring your own "coverflow" effects but RV now supports horizontal stuff and snapping.

Comment: Alternatively... fork the library, and modify [their custom layout manager](https://github.com/ChenLittlePing/RecyclerCoverFlow/blob/master/coverflow/src/main/java/recycler/coverflow/CoverFlowLayoutManger.java) to work backwards when the locale is RTL. I haven't tried this, and wouldn't know exactly where this is needed without trying it myself, but that's where I'd start looking. (it also appears the author left comments in what looks like Japanese -don't quote me on that- and I don't speak it so good luck there) ;)